# Spark - Hive table returnig null value on shell

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to pull hive table data on spark shell using spark.sql(" ") but it's giving null values.
Hive table contains data. Even I have written code using HiveContext object but still same issue persists.

Comment: Hi please paste your code for better help

Comment: spark.sql("select * from dbname.tablename ").show()

Comment: 1. What is the spark version that is used?
2. The number of nulls records is equal to number of records in table?
3. Does the data have case-sensitive schema(`spark.read.parquet(<path>).printSchema`)?
4. Can we set `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode=INFER_AND_SAVE` and try to read the data

Comment: 1) version : 2.2

Comment: 1) Version : 2.2 2) yes ( same record count is there) 3) how can we check data schema either case-sensitive or not 4) Enabled option caseSensitiveInferenceMode.  It's working for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 hc=SQLContext(sc) 
 hc.sql("select * from <dbname>.<tablename> ").show()
```

Comment: It's not working. Tried option as caseSensitiveInferenceMode=INFER_AND_SAVE , it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting spark.sql.warehouse.dir to that of your Hive Warehouse Directory instead of /user/hive/warehouse, and hive.metastore.uris to your thrift server

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("YourName")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
  .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```